# Can't find Android SDK from Google's site for Android Studio setup

Tags: android, android-studio

Installed Android Studio 1.1 and upon launched, it's asking for the path to the Android SDK. Clicking on the link to download the SDK, it brought me back to the place where I downloaded Android Studio.  The SDK tools on the site doesn't contain the SDK either.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Android Studio contains the Android SDK. Just look into the downloaded folder. If you want to download the stand-alone SDK Tools go to the [website.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

Comment: Downloaded file is not a folder - it's a dmg file and in it there is only one thing - Android Studio.app.  The sdk is not inside the .app bundle either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the sdk folder will go into the applications contents folder so you should be able to find it if you look in there. Otherwise at the bottom of the page that you downloaded android studio from there should be a link to download the sdk separately, which you can store anywhere on your computer and put the location in the dialog

Comment: It's not in the application contents folder.  I looked at it everywhere.  The link took me back to where I downloaded Android Studio.

Comment: At the bottom of this page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
there is a section that says SDK only. Download the applicable version to get just the sdks